# Accessing input with class inside div with id

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this structure and elements that I would like to change values or add a list to input.

```
<div id="TtkGjK6BoO" class="sc-fzoant fuKkxE">
  <div class="sc-AxjAm fxBnch">
    <div id="kit-container" class="sc-AxirZ ihpBRB">
      <h1>Title?</h1>
      <form><input class="sc-fznWOq iEYfe" value=""></form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know this id for sure and class for sure, but class is not unique and I don't have input id, only class. How do I access the input, since, something like this does not work:

```
$('#TtkGjK6BoO.sc-fznWO.iEYfe').val('Hi'));
```

Comment: Put a space before the first `.`. Selectors with no spaces mean that you're looking for a single element meeting all those requirements. The space indicates a delineation between a parent and child element. For future reference, the jQuery selector engine uses standard CSS rules, so this may help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors

Comment: `$('#TtkGjK6BoO .iEYfe').val('Hi')` will work just as well and if `iEYfe` is unique, then so will `$('.iEYfe').val('Hi');`

Comment: No, the iEYfe is not unique, so I cannot access it directly, so I need to find div which has this particular class input. But the first one worked fine :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can search by hierarchy!

```js
$('div > h1 + form > input').val('Hello');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="TtkGjK6BoO" class="sc-fzoant fuKkxE">
  <div class="sc-AxjAm fxBnch">
    <div id="kit-container" class="sc-AxirZ ihpBRB">
      <h1>Title?</h1>
      <form><input class="sc-fznWOq iEYfe" value=""></form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a space before sub element selectors

Assuming iEYfe is unique inside the container with ID TtkGjK6BoO then this will work

```
$('#TtkGjK6BoO .iEYfe').val('Hi');
```